The filters that I apply on Specific filed I cant see that filter working on Community Site
What is confusing me I set the visibility filter for the custom filed on the lead Object that is actually working but the same filed visibility is not working on the Community Site.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
